# html form using PHP_SELF & php validation - after submit, results displayed on new page without displaying form

Tags: php, html, forms

I am trying to create an html search form using a similar code as posted below.

When I submit the form, I want to submit to PHP_SELF

I want to use php validation code to filter the data.

When I submit the form, I cannot figure out how to get the results to post to a new page without displaying the form.

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "xyz_database";

// Create connection

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection

if ($conn->connect_error) {

die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);

}


$showHtml = true;   

$month = $day = $year = "";

$monthErr = $dayErr = $yearErr =  "";

$errorMessage = "Oops..Please correct the item(s) highlighted in red on the form below and re-submit";

 function test_input($data) {  

   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);

   return $data;
 }


if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {


// Month error & filter check code....

 if (empty($_POST["month"])) {

 $month = "";

 } else {

 $month = test_input($_POST["month"]);

 if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$month)) {

  $monthErr = "An invalid entry has been detected. Please reset this form and re-submit.";

  }
  }


 // Day error & filter check code....

   if (empty($_POST["day"])) {

   $day = "";

   } else {

   $day = test_input($_POST["day"]);

   if (!is_numeric($day)) {

  $dayErr = "Day Found - An invalid entry has been detected. Please reset this form and re-submit.";

 }
 }

  // Year error & filter check code....

  if (empty($_POST["year"])) {

  $year = "";

  } else {

  $year = test_input($_POST["year"]);

  if (!is_numeric($year)) {

  $yearErr = "Year Found - An invalid entry has been detected. Please reset this form and re-submit.";


  }
   }


 if (empty($monthErr) and empty($dayErr)  and empty($yearErr)) {


 $showHtml = false;  


$value1 = $_POST['month'];
$value2 = $_POST['day'];
$value3 = $_POST['year'];


 $sql = "SELECT * FROM xyz_test_database WHERE month = ('$value1') AND day =     ('$value2') AND year = ('$value3')";

 $result = $conn->query($sql);


if ($result->num_rows > 0) {echo "<br><br><h2>Search Results</h2>
                       <table><tr>
                                  <th>ID</th> 
                                  <th>Time Stamp</th>
                                  <th>Month</th>                                 
                                  <th>Day</th>
                                  <th>Year</th>
                             </tr>";

 // output data of each row

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "<tr>
          <td>".$row["id"]."</td>
          <td>".$row["time_stamp"]."</td>
          <td>".$row["month"]."</td>
          <td>".$row["day"]."</td>
          <td>".$row["year"]."</td>
      </tr>";
 }

 echo "</table>";

 } else {


  echo "<p id='no_results'>Sorry - No Results Found :( </p>";

  }
  }
  }


  $conn->close();

  exit ();

 ?>

 <?php

 if ($showHtml)

 {

 ?>


 <!DOCTYPE html>

 <meta charset="UTF-8">

 <html>

 <head>
 </head>

 <body>

 <form name="form1" method="POST" action="<?php echo     htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">  


 <select id="item_select" name="month">


       <option value="">Select Month</option>
       <option value="January">January</option>
       <option value="February">February</option>
       <option value="March">March</option>
       <option value="April">April</option>
       <option value="May">May</option>
       <option value="June">June</option>
       <option value="July">July</option>
       <option value="August">August</option>
       <option value="September">September</option>
       <option value="October">October</option>
       <option value="November">November</option>
       <option value="December">December</option>

   </select>

 &nbsp;&nbsp;

 <select id="item_select" name="day">

         <option value="">Day</option>
         <option value="1">1</option>
         <option value="2">2</option>
         <option value="3">3</option>
         <option value="4">4</option>
         <option value="5">5</option>
         <option value="6">6</option>
         <option value="7">7</option>
         <option value="8">8</option>
         <option value="9">9</option>
         <option value="10">10</option>

   </select>

 &nbsp;&nbsp;

 <select id="item_select" name="year">

         <option value="">Year</option>
         <option value="2015">2015</option>
         <option value="2014">2014</option>
         <option value="2013">2013</option>
         <option value="2012">2012</option>
         <option value="2011">2011</option>
         <option value="1975">1975</option>
  </select>

<br>

 <span class="error"><?php echo $monthErr;?></span>
 <span class="error"><?php echo $dayErr;?></span>
 <span class="error"><?php echo $yearErr;?></span>

 <br>

    <input type="Submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Search" style="width: 120px; color: blue;"/>

</form>

</body>

</html>

<?php

}

?>
```

Comment: `PHP_SELF` is an unwise method to use . Read http://www.mc2design.com/blog/article/serverphp_self-can-not-be-trusted-but-there-are-safe-alternatives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "xyz_database";

// Create connection

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection

if ($conn->connect_error) {

die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);

}


$showHtml = true;   

$month = $day = $year = "";

$monthErr = $dayErr = $yearErr =  "";

$errorMessage = "Oops..Please correct the item(s) highlighted in red on the form below and re-submit";

function test_input($data) {  

$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);

return $data;
}


if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {


 // Month error & filter check code....

if (empty($_POST["month"])) {

$month = "";

} else {

$month = test_input($_POST["month"]);

if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$month)) {

$monthErr = "An invalid entry has been detected. Please reset this form and re-submit.";

}
}


  // Day error & filter check code....

  if (empty($_POST["day"])) {

 $day = "";

 } else {

 $day = test_input($_POST["day"]);

 if (!is_numeric($day)) {

$dayErr = "Day Found - An invalid entry has been detected. Please reset this form and re-submit.";

 }
 }

// Year error & filter check code....

if (empty($_POST["year"])) {

$year = "";

} else {

$year = test_input($_POST["year"]);

if (!is_numeric($year)) {

$yearErr = "Year Found - An invalid entry has been detected. Please reset this form and re-submit.";


}
 }


if (empty($monthErr) and empty($dayErr)  and empty($yearErr)) {


$showHtml = false;  


$value1 = $_POST['month'];
$value2 = $_POST['day'];
$value3 = $_POST['year'];


 $sql = "SELECT * FROM xyz_test_database WHERE month = ('$value1') AND day =     ('$value2') AND year = ('$value3')";

 $result = $conn->query($sql);


if ($result->num_rows > 0) {echo "<br><br><h2>Search Results</h2>
                   <table><tr>
                              <th>ID</th> 
                              <th>Time Stamp</th>
                              <th>Month</th>                                 
                              <th>Day</th>
                              <th>Year</th>
                         </tr>";

  // output data of each row

  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     echo "<tr>
      <td>".$row["id"]."</td>
      <td>".$row["time_stamp"]."</td>
      <td>".$row["month"]."</td>
      <td>".$row["day"]."</td>
      <td>".$row["year"]."</td>
   </tr>";
 }

echo "</table>";

} else {


 echo "<p id='no_results'>Sorry - No Results Found :( </p>";

 }
 }
 }


 $conn->close();

 exit ();

 ?>

<?php

if ($showHtml)

 {

 ?>


 <!DOCTYPE html>

 <meta charset="UTF-8">

 <html>

 <head>
 </head>

 <body>

  <form name="form1" method="POST" action="<?php echo     htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">  


 <select id="item_select" name="month">


   <option value="">Select Month</option>
   <option value="January">January</option>
   <option value="February">February</option>
   <option value="March">March</option>
   <option value="April">April</option>
   <option value="May">May</option>
   <option value="June">June</option>
   <option value="July">July</option>
   <option value="August">August</option>
   <option value="September">September</option>
   <option value="October">October</option>
   <option value="November">November</option>
   <option value="December">December</option>

  </select>

 &nbsp;&nbsp;

 <select id="item_select" name="day">

     <option value="">Day</option>
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
     <option value="4">4</option>
     <option value="5">5</option>
     <option value="6">6</option>
     <option value="7">7</option>
     <option value="8">8</option>
     <option value="9">9</option>
     <option value="10">10</option>

  </select>

 &nbsp;&nbsp;

  <select id="item_select" name="year">

     <option value="">Year</option>
     <option value="2015">2015</option>
     <option value="2014">2014</option>
     <option value="2013">2013</option>
     <option value="2012">2012</option>
     <option value="2011">2011</option>
     <option value="1975">1975</option>
   </select>

  <br>

  <span class="error"><?php echo $monthErr;?></span>
  <span class="error"><?php echo $dayErr;?></span>
  <span class="error"><?php echo $yearErr;?></span>

  <br>

  <input type="Submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Search" style="width: 120px; color: blue;"/>

  </form>

  </body>

  </html>

 <?php

  }

  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to achieve this.  You can put an if statement around your html code so that it only displays if certain conditions (e.g. results aren't returned) are met.

One really simple way of doing this is to set a boolean value if results are returned.  For example:

```
<?php

$showHtml = true;

...

if($result->num_rows > 0)
{
    $showHtml = false;
    ...

}

...

$conn->close();

if($showHtml)
{

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

...

</html>

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help....Your answer makes perfect sense, but I just can't seem to make it work. The page just keeps going straight to the "no results found" result without showing the html form when I refresh the page.

Comment: Can you show your code or upload it somewhere?  Are you getting any errors?

Comment: I just edited my original posting with the code that has my last attempt to incorporate the $showHtml = true; / false idea you gave me.

Comment: You don't need the echo after if(showHtml) and you forgot the opening <?php tag at the end before the close }.  You don't need '; before the bracket either.

Comment: I just adjusted it...same thing...when I refresh the page, goes straight to the "no results found" code output. Its got to be something simple.

Comment: It works....for some reason it was the "exit ( );" code that was keeping it from working correctly. Thank you so much for all your time and thought. I really appreciate it.